# Messy and overlapping plot when use pyplot.subplot and seaborns

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization, outliers

I tried to visualize outliers using seaborn

```py
columns =list(df_main.select_dtypes(['int64', 'float64']).columns)

for i, column in enumerate(columns):
  plt.subplot(19,1,1+i)
  sns.boxplot(x=df_main[column], orient="h")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This is the result I'm getting:

[image]

Is there any advice to make it readable? I'm open to any techniques for visualizing the outliers. Thanks in advance

edit:
The output that I desire may look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You melt your dataframe and use a facet plot in seaborn, for example using sns.catplot. Example dataset:

```py
df_main = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(i,1,100) for i in range(19)]).T
```

Running your code, looks like this:

[image]

Using sns.catplot:

```
sns.catplot(row="variable",x="value",
data=df_main.melt(),kind="box",height=0.8,aspect=7)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe try this code and tell me if your problem is solved? This is the general structure I use for my plots.

```
columns =list(df_main.select_dtypes(['int64', 'float64']).columns)

grid = plt.GridSpec(19, 1)
figure = plt.figure()

for i, column in enumerate(columns):
  ax = figure.add_subplot(grid[i])
  sns.boxplot(x=df_main[column], orient="h", ax=ax)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: the output still messy, sir

Comment: I have edited my answer with an alternative. I believe its unneccessary to make a new answer. Would be nice if you could try it with this one. Else I have to admit that I can't help. I would need the data to recreate your problem. Sry